# Can I set the distance between lines of type in Fontlab Sutdio 5?

Tags: font-design, fontlab-studio

I am using Fontlab Studio 5 on Windows.

I am working on a ttf font design in Fontlab Studio and I am aware I can use Metrics to set the space between the various characters but can I set the space or distance between lines of type?

I know that in most Word processors or, for example, Adobe Illustrator you would use the line spacing or paragraph features but can this be actually set within the font metrics?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typography, the distance between adjacent lines of type is called **Leading**.

In Fontlab Studio 5, the simplest way to adjust it is using a property called **TypoLineGap**. To access it, use the menu *File* > *Font Info...* (or press *Ctrl+Alt+F*). From the options tree in the left, select *Metrics and Dimensions* > *TrueType-specific metrics*, and click the option *Set custom values*. Before changing the *TypoLineGap*, press once the *Recalculate* button, in order to allow Fontlab to choose the recommended values for the other parameters, and only then play with the *TypoLineGap* value.

You can check the effect entering some text in the *Preview* panel. In order to insert a new line, type **\n** between lines of text.

**NOTE:** This is the simplest way, but it has technical details you may have to address. Check this [Font Metrics Manual](https://www.kltf.de/downloads/FontMetrics-kltf.pdf).